# Query database table with two list of values to get distinct column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables in Postgres

```
Employee: 
    EmployeeId, 
    EmployeeName,
    EmployeeSal, 
    PrimaryKey(EmployeeId)

EmployeeBonus: 
    BonusCode, 
    BonusAmount, 
    EmployeeId, 
    PrimaryKey(BonusCode, EmployeeId)
```

We have around 50 BonusCodes, and EmployeeBonus table has 15 million rows

I have following data in a java program.

1. List of Employee ids (around 20000)
2. List of Bonus Codes (around 80000)

The above data is in a Map like below. I can get the list of BonusCode's list for each employee
(EmployeeId, List(BonusCodes))

Now my requirement in a Java program is to find out records from EmployeeBonus table with unique combination of BonusCode and EmployeeId 
using the provided 2 lists.

Can any one help me to find the best possible way to find the results with good performance.

**Query1:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT BonusCode, EmployeeId 
FROM EmployeeBonus;
```

Get the existing results(around 15 million), and process them in java program
But this query is throwing OutOfMemoryError in java program, as the size of the data is huge.

**Query2:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT BonusCode, EmployeeId 
FROM EmployeeBonus 
WHERE EmployeeId = :EmployeeId 
  AND BonusCode IN (:BonusCodeList);
```

By looping over EmployeeId list and executing the above query multiple times with list of BonusCode's
Working fine but taking lot of time to execute multiple queries and collect results

**Query3:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT BonusCode, EmployeeId 
FROM EmployeeBonus 
WHERE BonusCode = :BonusCode 
  AND EmployeeId IN (:EmployeeIdList);
```

By looping over BonusCode list and executing the above query multiple times with list of EmployeeId's
Working fine but taking lot of time to execute multiple queries and collect results

**Query4:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT BonusCode, EmployeeId 
FROM EmployeeBonus 
WHERE EmployeeId IN (:EmployeeIdList) 
  AND BonusCode IN (:BonusCodeList);
```

However this is not the list of data that I want

Comment: If you ultimately need the result from query 1 then you need to increase the memory. One reason for the memory problem could be that the JDBC driver buffers the whole result in memory before returning from the `executeQuery()` call. But you can change that, see the manual: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: I don't see how your question is specifically about Java or JDBC. I'd suggest to solve this purely in SQL.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I do think the JDBC tag is OK as the query is executed through JDBC and the behaviour of the driver _could_ be the reason for the memory problem

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In that case it the Java code should be included as well.

Comment: The two lists Employee ids (1) and Bonus codes (2) should be saved in a table. Then you let the sql engine do what it is good at. If the data is dynamic, then it may mean you have to build a mechanism to load the data.  May seem like more work, but I found loading and querying to usually be the best approach.